# Format each letter in a field that I get back from database with SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, conditional-formatting

I have a requirement where I want to format a field that is returned from the database based on what it contains.  Specifically, if the value of the field is "Other 3", I need to display the "Other" in 12pt and the "3" in 8pt.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reference the field in two textboxes.  Use `Mid` & `IndexOf` to select either side of the field for each textbox.  Then just set the fonts of each textbox to 12pt and 8pt.

If it is mandatory that entire string exist in one textbox, (and you're using SSRS 2008) you can use placeholders as described [here](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/Daniel/ssas/1574/ssrs-multiple-fonts-sizes-and-colors-in-a-single-text-box).

Comment: Based on this, I ended up modifying what I was returning from the database to have two fields.  One with the data and one with the footnote.  I then, created two place holders, one for each field.  I made the footnote one a smaller script and it gave me exactly what I wanted.